# IF function; struggling with format of 3 times greater section

Tags: if-statement

Excel 2002: Write an IF function for cell J8 that assigns the text "OK" if the value in cell L9 is three times greater than the value in cell M6; otherwise, have the IF function assign the text "Not OK" to cell J8. would it be: =if(L9*3>m6, "OK", "Not OK")

Answer (score 0):

That would be
=IF(L9>=M6*3,"OK", "Not OK")

further examples:

```
A   B   C           Formula
-------------------------------------------------
1   2   No OK       IF(B2 >= A2*3,"OK", "Not OK")
2   6   OK          IF(B3 >= A3*3,"OK", "Not OK")
3   8   No OK       IF(B4 >= A4*3,"OK", "Not OK")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the quick response!